# Google AppEngine Node.js: Deploying API and WepApp

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm new to GoogleCloud. 
I've followed the tutorial (for Node.js) with these steps:

1. Build my own **My-Hello-World** web app
2. Deploy to AppEngine
3. It works fine as **https://My-Hello-World.appspot.com**
4. Build my own EndPoints APIs with project-id as **My-Hello-World**
5. Deploy to AppEngine
6. It also works fine as **https://My-Hello-World.appspot.com/api/test/***

My problem is the moment I deploy EndPoints APIs, my **My-Hello-World.appspot.com** doesn't run as webapp anymore, it responses as APIs. How to config to make my project run for both webapp and api when deploy to AppEngine?

https://My-Hello-World.appspot.com --> run as webapp

https://My-Hello-World.appspot.com/api/test/* --> run as api

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So assuming that

- Your Endpoints API and Webapp are in the same GCP project
- Each has their own `app.yaml`

You can deploy them to the same project's app engine and have them run together as separate services. All you will need to do is add a service tag in your `app.yaml`

```
service: api
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV : staging
```

This is what mine looks like for a ExpressJS RestAPI that I deploy to staging.

You can keep the web-app's `app.yaml` the same, because it will be used as the *default* service.

Then you will be able to access

- Webapp

  - https ==> my-hello-world.appspot.com
  - http  ==> my-hello-world.appspot.com
- API

  - https ==> api-dot-my-hello-world.appspot.com
  - http  ==> api.my-hello-world.appspot.com

---

Reference

- [How Requests are Routed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-requests-are-routed)
- [Configuring your app with app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml)

Comment: Put them all into 1 project and deploy does work. But I'm trying to do is deploy my webapp and my endpoint separately to GAE, so later, if I modify my APIs and re-deploy, it won't effect the running webapp

Comment: You can deploy multiple service completely independent of each other to the same project.  When you set the service name in your app.yaml then they are managed as seperate microservices.  So you could update your API and your Webapp would remain untouched.

Comment: The "service_name" in app.yaml does work but I have to set different name ! Thank you for the help :)